# Code generation for a secured web service using Restlet Odata extension

Tags: odata, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am trying to create object model (java classes) using Restlet Odata extesnion for my secured webservice. As part of this process, I wrote below code to generate the code.

```
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator;
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Service;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeResponse;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;

public class ODataRestletGenerator extends Service {

    public ODataRestletGenerator(String serviceUri) {
        super(serviceUri);
    }

    public static final String APPLICATION_URI = "https://api5.successfactors.eu/odata/v2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Add the client authentication to the call
        ChallengeScheme scheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
        ChallengeResponse credentials = new ChallengeResponse(scheme, "user", "pwd");       
        new ODataRestletGenerator(APPLICATION_URI).setauth(credentials);

        String[] arguments = { APPLICATION_URI, "/src/main/java" };
        Generator.main(arguments);
    }

    private void setauth(ChallengeResponse credentials) {

        super.setCredentials(credentials);
    }

}
```

But the below code in org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator class is clearing the credentials what I am passing and it is always throwing 401 unauthorized error.

```
Service service = new Service(dataServiceUri);
if(service.getMetadata() == null)
{
  errorMessage = "Cannot retrieve the metadata.";
}
```

Can you please fix this issue and provide support to generate code for secured webservices as well?

Thanks 
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer to restlet-as-OData-client, but if what you look for is a client, Apache Olingo could be a good alternative:

It supports latest ODataV4 protocol, generates strong-typed java classes from EDM model, etc...

You may want to check it out @ http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/maven.html, and there is a complete sample project of generating code @ https://github.com/Tirasa/olingoClientOnAndroidSample/blob/master/pom.xml